# How to Fix Multi-Character Constant Warning

Tags: c, arrays, character-encoding, char

I am working on a homework assignment where we are to exploit a program vulnerable to a buffer overflow. We do this by creating a large `char` array and first filling it entirely with no operation instructions.

I believe what I am supposed to do is copy malicious code into somewhere in the buffer (this part I can do fine), and then modify the return address of the exploitable function somehow so that it points to where the malicious code is.

I know the address I would like to set (let's say `½¾¿º`), but I'm getting some warnings and don't know what they are caused by.

This is the code (essentially) that is causing the warning:

```
int start_of_return_address = 10;
chars[start_of_return_address + 0] = '½';
chars[start_of_return_address + 1] = '¾';
chars[start_of_return_address + 2] = '¿';
chars[start_of_return_address + 3] = 'º';
```

The warnings I get for each assignment are:

```
warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion
warning: multi-character character constant
```

I got the address by converting `bdbebfba` (address of malicious code) into characters (yielding `½¾¿º`).

Any ideas as to what might be causing the warning, or another way I can copy an address into a character array?

Please keep in mind that this is for homework.

Comment: How did you convert `bdbebfba` into 'characters'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your conversion from `bdbebfba` to characters is suspect.

If that is the address, and if I would want to store it in a character array I would do:

```
chars[start_of_return_address + 0] = 0xbd;
chars[start_of_return_address + 1] = 0xbe;
chars[start_of_return_address + 2] = 0xbf;
chars[start_of_return_address + 3] = 0xba;
```

It is a 4 byte value, so it *will* fit into 4 characters.

I think [endian-ness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is also important. If the system is little-endian (x86), then the least significant byte goes into the lower address (and you reverse the order of assignment).

```
chars[start_of_return_address + 4] = 0xbd;
chars[start_of_return_address + 3] = 0xbe;
chars[start_of_return_address + 2] = 0xbf;
chars[start_of_return_address + 1] = 0xba;
```

Comment: This was it! Thank you! This endian-ness was indeed an important factor (2nd set of code works), so thank you also for making that edit.

Answer (score 1):

The character literals you are showing us (`'½'`, `'¾'`, `'¿'`, `'º'`) shouldn't be interpreted as multicharacter constants.  As they are, my guess is that it is an encoding problem: for instance they could be encoded as UTF-8 (and thus as two bytes) in the source, but the compiler expect another encoding (says the Latin-1 you assumed -- if I'm right they are seen as `'Â½'`, `'Â¾'`, `'Â¿'`, `'Âº'`) and thus consider that there is two characters in the constant.